# Button onclick is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have an MVC application where I use more `views`, `partial views`.

In one `partial view` I have two buttons:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceShow" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:test()">@Resources.Common.ShowInvoice</button>
<button type="submit" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate" class="btn btn-success btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate">@Resources.Common.Generate</button>
```

I need to put some logic in javascript when I click these buttons, but it seems the onclick event is not raised, it does nothing when I click the buttons.

The buttons are in a partial view, in the "parent" view I have added the code:

```
  $("#btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate").on("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log("asas");
            //var companyId = $('input[name=IssuerCompanyId]:checked').val();
            var action_url = '@Url.Action("GenerateInvoiceDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Area = "", id = @ViewBag.Id })';
            window.location = action_url;
            this.disabled = true;
        });
```

I have tried to add this code inside the

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

I have tried to add to add outside the

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
```

from the "parent" view.

If I try to use the method that it is defined in the onclick event from the button,

```
function test()
{
    console.log("test");
}
```

I get the error that `test is not defined`. If I put the javascript code in the partial view it is working with

```
  $("#btnSilviPrioInvoiceShow").on("click", function (e) {
```

, but all the javascript code is in the "parent" view, so I thought it would be better to add there the javascript code. 
Can you advise?

Comment: Change them to `type="button"` - also remove the useless `javascript:` label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your button like following:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceShow" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test()">@Resources.Common.ShowInvoice</input>
    <input type="button" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate" class="btn btn-success btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate">@Resources.Common.Generate</input>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, this example works correctly, remove `javascript:` label

```js
$("#btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate clicked");
});

function test() {
  console.log("it is test function");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceShow" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test()">@Resources.Common.ShowInvoice</button>
<button type="submit" id="btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate" class="btn btn-success btnSilviPrioInvoiceGenerate">@Resources.Common.Generate</button>
```